# Where can I download JavaFX Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to download JavaFX Scene Builder that I would want to use with Eclipse. I have installed the JavaFX plug -in for Eclipse Luna, now I want to download the JavaFX Scene Builder but I cannot locate it on [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). I have searched under [Additional Resources](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) as instructed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/installation-guide/jfxsb-installation_2_0.htm) but could not see the link to download it.

Is the provided link valid? Where can I download JavaFx Scene Builder?

Comment: Depending on if you search a current version of the Scene Builder that should be the explanation: http://java.dzone.com/articles/bye-bye-javafx-scene-builder. You have to build it from source !

Comment: Here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html @Marged You do not have  to build it from source.

Comment: @Marged I am not sure how to build it from source, is there a guideline to do so?

Comment: @EvanKnowlesIf I understand the linked site correctly (I know it is not officially from Oracle) starting with a certain version you will only get the sources. Because of that someone else decided to provide the binaries.

Comment: I got the latest version of scene builder from Gluon http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems finding it from the Oracle website. A Google search with the search term "javafx scene builder download" helped. After I found it, I added the following direct link as a reference into our "How to set up my development environment" document:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html

And I always keep a copy of the download in our SVN (*$/environment*) in case the link breaks.